# How to discover all available Emacs packages?

Tags: package, list-packages

How can I discover all available packages of Emacs?

So far, I was under the impression that I could find almost anything through one of these means:

- The Emacs Manual (`C-h r`)
- `M-x list-packages`
- `C-h p`

But it does not seem enough. As an example, I came upon `rcirc` (an IRC client) online. I could not find it in the above resources. Is it a built-in package? How can I know? Is there a place where all features are listed?

Comment: `rcirc` is built-in.  I personally use `grep` command-line utility and also the well known Google to figure out most of what I need to know and it turns out the Emacs manual has a section regarding the aforementioned library:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/rcirc/Getting-started-with-rcirc.html  You may wish to Google how to search the built-in Emacs documentation, such as the Emacs manual and other info files for the various built-in libraries.  And, other sources can be added to the `list-packages` feature; e.g., MELPA, Marmalade, and some others.  Some is on Github.

Comment: You could try `M-x TAB TAB` to see all `M-x` commands avaiable to you at a given moment, but you won't see everything because not all libraries that emacs comes with are loaded on start.

Comment: If you use `helm` or `ivy` they allow to brows loaded functions and variables easily.

Comment: I wonder why `list-packages` lists some of the built-in packages and not others (such as rcirc). At any rate, it seems `M-x describe-package` does include rcirc, so maybe it's list is better for the built-in packages. You could run `M-x describe-package` and press TAB to popup the completions buffer to get a package list.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried to find a way to identify all packages in a way similar to `list-packages`, but it seems not all libraries are considered as packages so they are not listed among other packages.

There are a few ways of identify what is built-in into Emacs:

1. Official Manuals which cover a lot of things, including manuals for various packages including RCIRC: [GNU Emacs Manuals Online](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/index.html)
2. Browse `lisp/` directory of your Emacs installation or CVS tree online (e.g., [master of emacs-27](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp)), find .el files and look at the header. You can automate this stuff with grep like this (you might need to tweak this regexp):

   ```
   grep -r -E ';;;.*\.el\s+---\s+.*' <path-to-emacs-installation>/lisp
   ```

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/5sgr2y/is_there_a_list_of_emacs_builtin_packages/).

The output gives about 1400 lines (emacs-26.1.50), some of which are just libraries or minor modes. For example, here's the output for rcirc:

```
net/rcirc.el:;;; rcirc.el --- default, simple IRC client
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation about `package.el` should be improved (see [bug #29420](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=29420)). I think `list-packages` does not list all packages available on the system but only displays manageable packages (c.f. the built-in [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/efaq.html#Packages-that-do-not-come-with-Emacs)).

> The idea behind `package.el` is to be able to *download packages and install them*. Packages are vers­ioned and have versioned dependencies. Furthermore, this supports built-in packages which may or may not be newer than user-specified packages. This makes it possible to upgrade Emacs and automatically disable packages which have moved from external to core. (Note though that we don't currently regis­ter any of these, so this feature does not actually work.)

On the other hand, the command `describe-package` seems to list packages.

```
M-x describe-package
?
<select the *Completion* window>
C-x h
M-w
<create-a-new-buffer>
C-y
```

Nevertheless, it is not a convenient command to display the available packages (but you can look at the [source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/emacs-lisp/package.el#n2247) or file a feature request (bug report)).

Answer (score 0):

`helm-locate-library` from the [Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm) package gives all libraries.

It works by going through all files / directories in `load-path` and finding resources that can be loaded.